# change position of headline / \insertnavigation beamer

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I wanted to widen the beamer page, which I did in my stlye file using `\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.2cm}` etc. I was able to ensure that (i) frametitle is inserted with the same margin (`\leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin \advance\leftskip by0.2cm`) and (ii) the footline also has the same margin (`\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.2cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{title in head/foot`} etc.), basically by hacking standard style files. 
What I failed to do through experimenting was to have the headline (navigation, i.e., section heads or titles) use the same left and right margins. I would have though that passing the width argument {`wd=\paperwidth`} or {`wd=\textwidth`} to `\insertnavigation` would set it to the same margins as the `\setbeamersize{text margin ...` commands, but it does not, as these sizes appear independent of the defined text margins. The one thing that had an effect is the introduction of an `\hskip` command, paired with changing wd to a higher proportion of `\pagewidth` (e.g., 1.03), but the effect of these parameters on the output is not continuous, and could not get the desired outcome.
I am hopeful that there is a **correct**, elegant solution. Can anyone point it out to me?
Thanks a lot.
Nicolae

Comment: Please always accompany your descriptions with a complete, minimal document showing the relevant settings and allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I really don't know how to provide a short yet meaningful example.

Comment: Here's what I meant to write: I really don't know how to provide a short yet meaningful example. I was hopeful that my description was sufficiently clear -- I want to be able to set the left coordinate where the section head is shown as a result of \insertnavigation.